# Rails disable JSON parsing of POST/PUT/PATCH body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration

I want to take a large JSON PUT request and process it entirely in the background with Sidekiq. As such, I do not want to automatically parse the incoming JSON from the request's body.

Whats the best practice for accomplishing this on a controller/action-based level?

Comment: Maybe just use another content-type for that request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know this is done via Rack middleware, so I don't think you can just disable it for one controller/action right out of the box.  You can patch `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser` similar to what this guy did:

http://www.jkfill.com/2015/02/21/skip-automatic-params-parsing/

You, of course, can write your own middleware that parses the parameters, or specify a custom parser for JSON MIME type.

At last, you can disable the JSON parsing all together.  In your config/application.rb add:

```
 config.middleware.swap ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, Mime::JSON => nil
```

Comment: That would apply the change to the entire application, you probably do not want that, check out http://icelab.com.au/articles/wrapping-rack-middleware-to-exclude-certain-urls-for-rails-streaming-responses/ on how to apply middleware changes depending on URIhttp://icelab.com.au/articles/wrapping-rack-middleware-to-exclude-certain-urls-for-rails-streaming-responses/